# xml with cdata html sections using jaxb to convert to java objects ...is it possible to render the html?

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-parsing

I have an xml document that I used JAXB to ultimately have struts2 display in a webpage.

This document at a high level contains CDATA sections that are paragraphs that contain some HTML.  The java object returned is a list of the paragraph objects whose text gets turned into strings.

When I display them in the JSP I get the paragraphs outputted to the screen and they contain HTML but it is not rendered.

I have found answers on here about removing HTML from java strings but nothing like this. I also don't have control over the XML document I only consume it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) has the @XmlCDATA annotation for handling CDATA (I'm the tech lead).  This may help if you can use MOXy as your JAXB implementation.

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/cdata-cdata-run-run-data-run.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. After further reviewing my question I realized that my issue is not in the parsing because the HTML is coming through its with the struts tag I am using to output the value.

Comment: @basZero - We introduced the `@XmlCDATA` annotation in EclipseLink MOXy 2.2.  In EclipseLink MOXy 2.1.2 you could configure a CDATA property via the XML metadata document:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: Many thanks Blaise, I implemented a workaround at this moment. An upgrade to 2.2 is coming anyways, so I'll use the latest annotation then. I hope it works! :)

Comment: Can anyone point how to implement this solution to client where I don't initialize `JAXBContext jc = (JAXBContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, props);` like this? I use wsdl2java generated client.

Comment: Answer to my question lies here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html